# When to use Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco5

I am a asp.net webforms developer (have 4 years of expirience), and have some expirience with MVC and razor engine + normal front end like jquery/templating and so on. Im used to build sites up from scratch. Yesterday ive got an idea to learn one of the CMS systems which everybody talks about. I chose Umbraco to be the system of my choice. Ive lerned some basics like templating, document types, content handling and so on.

Right now i really dont see when i should use umbraco and when to use plain asp.net webforms/MVC to build a website.

Can anybody explain me what is it that make umbraco so good that alot of people use it? The only thing i can see is that it makes some clear structure of a webpage.

Comment: IMHO fundamentally, you need to know the difference between a **CMS** and the ASP.Net platform. As a developer you **will** need to know ASP.Net to extend/customize Umbraco to your specific needs.

Comment: I answered a question like this once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698543/how-to-develop-middle-large-size-project-with-umbraco/10837873#10837873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with all other Content Management Systems (CMS), they are build for the end-users to manage the content of their website in an easy way without the need of understanding, html, php or other programming languages.
Besides this, Umbraco is a powerful and flexible CMS build on the ASP.NET Framework and it is free and open-source.